# Table rows in segmented control wont scroll up when segment changes

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I have two segments `ONC` and  `OFC`, after data is displayed in `ONC segment` and I scroll it to `row15`, when I change the segment to `OFC`, it shows `row15` but I want it to show `row1`

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    var typeOfEvent = 0
    switch (eventSegCtrl.selectedSegmentIndex)
    {
    case 0:
        typeOfEvent = oncEvents.count
        break
    case 1:
        typeOfEvent = ofcEvents.count
        break
    default:break
    }

    return typeOfEvent
}
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Could you elaborate? how you scrolling to row 15? what's the purpose of adding `numberOfRowsInSection` as a code snippet?

Comment: I am just scrolling it to a random row (it can be row15 or row25), and other segmented control is showing the same random row(row 15 or row25) in previous segment, without showing top of the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is on reload of your `tableView` you can set its `contentOffset` to `CGPoint.zero`.

```
self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: false)
```

Comment: @Coder221 Welcome mate :)